# Probability of event occurring first given alternating group of people?

Tags: probability

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around this problem:

There are two groups A and B. There is a p<sub>0</sub> chance that a person in group A will fail and a p<sub>1</sub> chance that a person in group B will fail. People are assigned to the two groups alternating and outcomes are independent. What is the probability that the first failure happens in group A?

This is what I have: $p_0^np_1^{n-1}$. Where n is the number of rounds done of selection. I am unsure if I even need to use n or if this is correct.

Thank you

Comment: If the first failure happens in group A, either a person in group A fails, or a person in group A succeeds and a person in group B succeeds and a person in group A fails, or ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a little unclear, so I will be making assumptions.  Assignment starts with group A.  Failure occurs at the time of assignment. There is no limit to the total of people assigned.  In that case if the first failure is in group A after 2k assignments, the probability is $(1-p_0)^k(1-p_1)^kp_0$.   The total probability is $p_0\sum_{k=0}^\infty ((1-p_0)(1-p_1))^k =\frac{p_0}{1-(1-p_0)(1-p_1)}=\frac{p_0}{p_0+p_1-p_0p_1}$.